# Make a series of 250m buffers around a set of points using QGIS

Tags: point, buffer

I imported a set of points as a delimited text layer from a CSV. I'm trying to create another layer that puts 250m buffers/shapes around each point, so that I can eventually calculate the percentage of the underlying shape that's covered by the shapes/buffers.

This sounds really obvious - I've tried to run affine transform with a variety of scales but none of them actually create anything visible in the new layer. I've tried to use the buffer tool, but that seems to create massive shapes bigger than the underlying map basically no matter what distance I use.

Is this a CRS problem or do I need to turn the points into some other kind of feature, like a polygon?

I'm fairly new to QGIS, running 3.24.2-Tisler.

Comment: "I've tried to use the buffer tool, but that seems to create massive shapes bigger than the underlying map basically no matter what distance I use." - I guess your CRS is one based on degrees, hence buffers are in degrees, too. Reproject to a m-based CRS, then bffer again.

Comment: Not just a projected coordinate system with meters units, but a projected coordinate system which is equal area. Most certainly not Mercator (though UTM would be okay)

Comment: Thanks both, these are really useful - my underlying base map is OSGB36/British National Grid and my points are on WGS 84, so I'm having trouble finding a CRS that works for both, but I'll keep looking. If you have any ideas given that, it'd be much appreciated but no worries if not! @Vince

Comment: I'm now finding that whenever I reproject to an equal area based CRS, it moves my points and my map away from each other @Erik